# Pygmalion transformation: using "#define DLL" as replacement for "extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)"

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, declspec

Is there a way to use a svelte #define to transform the unsightly ""extern \"C\" __declspec(dllexport)" into a single, enchanting term "DLL".
That is:

```
#define DLL "extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)"
```

The problem, of course, is the embedded quote marks around the C.

Comment: Does it actually need the outermost quotes? Normally you don't.

Comment: Anything after `#define [name]` is the replacement for `[name]`, you don't need to use `"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the wrapping quotes.  The following is legit:

```
#define DLL extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
```